# Twitter gem find by user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

How do I do this, but by passing in the id instead of the screenname?

```
Twitter.user("sferik").location
```

Also where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Twitter.user(12345) # where 12345 is the id number
```

http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Client/Users#user-instance_method

Comment: Doesn't work: "Twitter::NotFound in Authentications#index ... GET https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=#######: 404: Not found". I am giving it a valid id #, coming from a variable called authentication.id.